# When I published my app.R to https://www.shinyapps.io/ I get this error

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I get this error:

> The application failed to start. exit status 1

but in my local app.R is run and load pages without any error.

This is the log 2

[image: Log file]

I tried to install dependency packages, but that did not work

Comment: You appear to be attempting to install shiny (`install.packages("shiny"): unable to install packages`) from within a shiny application (`Shiny application exiting`).  That makes no sense.

Comment: Limey is correct, saying it explicitly, your app should not include any install.package commands. rsconnect takes responsiblity for installing required packages when deploying apps